# reusing angular 9 component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a file upload component, `app-file-upload` that has a file type and a list of files variables. Everything works fine until I want to have multiple `app-file-upload` components on the same page.

What I am expecting is that when I click on the first file upload button, it would populate the list on the first `app-file-upload`. Then when I click on the second file upload button, the uploaded files would go to the second component's list.

What actually happens is that the second list of files would go to the first component's list. It is as if the second component is just a reference of the first.

Question: I know that angular services are created as singletons. So are components?? it wouldn't make sense because components are to be reused. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: maybe your actual upload-elements share the same name, id or whatever is used to identify the "unique" element ?

Comment: You should share us your component to check where is the issue.

Comment: @xDrago thank you. I think it might have been the id of the input. Let me try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @xDrago. I found the issue. I have a label that is for the input of type file (code below). All I need to do I generate a random number and assign to the `for` of the `label` and the `id` of the `input`.

```
 <label for="file-{{uniqueNumber}}" (click)="handleUploadClick()">
        <th-icon-upload></th-icon-upload>
        {{buttonText}}
    </label>
 <input type="file" id="file-{{uniqueNumber}}" [attr.multiple]="multiple ? '' : null" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)" accept="{{acceptableFiles}}" 
        [attr.disabled]="successFilesCount >= maximumNumberOfFiles ? '' : null" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple file upload component that works as you want.

Demo at this link: https://angular-upload-csvx.stackblitz.io/

Full code and extra: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upload-csvx

```js
//files.component.ts
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  'templateUrl': './files.component.html',
  'selector': 'app-files'
})

export class FilesComponent {
  handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    var file = files[0];
  }

}
```

```html
<!--files.component.html-->
<div>
  <form>
    <div>
      <input type="file" (change)="handleFileSelect($event)">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

```html
<!--app.component.html-->
<div>
  <app-files></app-files>
  <hr>
  <app-files></app-files>
  <hr>
  <app-files></app-files>  
</div>
```